# find out fullscreen button in youtube embedded player programatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, youtube

I wanted to know that is there any way to find out programatically the fullscreen button that is added on the youtube embedded player so that I can call an action on its touchupInsideEvent.

Please help. 
Thanks in advance. 
Shruti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it's not possible to intercept events like that into the flash player, unless the SWF has some sort of an API for that purpose.

A different way to approach the problem is to use the YouTube ["chromeless" player](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#player_apis). It's basically an embedded player with no user interface elements. You provide the controls, which can command the player via the Javascript interface. You can intercept a user request for maximize that way.

[There's even a question on Stack Overflow that concerns with fullscreen functionality for Chromeless players](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886006/youtube-chromeless-javascript-api-player-full-screen-button).

Comment: Thanx for your help. I really appreciate it. I will definitely try to do so n sorry for very late reply.